# Get tag by specified text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I need a simple solution for getting the DOM tag which contains a given text.

eg.

```
<body>
   <div id='example'>Hello world!</div>
</body>

<script>
  function GetTagInfo('Hello');
 //I wan't it to return the div as the object so I'll next update the    //content with another text. 
</script>
```

I don't want to use any regex, I need clean and simple code.

Comment: You want to interrogate _every_ element on the page, not just `div`s?

Comment: Why are we posting solutions here. This question isn't meeting standards. *I need clean and simple code.* == *Gimme teh codes*. 
To the OP. Welcome to SO. Have you read the part were it is explained how to write a good question on Stack Overflow? If not please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and/or http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes. It's my first post. Thank you very much for your note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use contains selector:

```
$('body *:contains("specified text")')//return div element(s) that contains specified text
```

However contains will not work for strict comparison. for strict comparison, you need to use filter function:

```
$('body *').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == "specified text";
});
```

Comment: What if the text is in a `span` or a `table`? OP didn't mention it had to be in a `div`.

Comment: @Andy: OP already shared the dom. there is no span/table element.

Comment: "a simple solution for get the DOM tag" - no mention of `div` there either. It was just an example.

Comment: have a look at shared markup. it has a div with text in it.

Comment: `<div id='example'>`: note the word "example".

Comment: Also, the title of the post is "Get tag by specified text", not "div".

Comment: well that does not mean people should start their predictions. as there are tons of it. saying nothing is gonna work from provided answer with those tons predictions :) . also contains will work in case when the div have any other element in it.

Comment: See the comment to the other question from the OP which confirms my suspicions.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a go:

```
function finder(query) {

    // get all elements
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    var out = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++) {

        // if the element isn't a script and doesn't contain any child
        // elements and the text contains whatever you passed
        // in as a query, add it to the out-going array
        if (elements[i].tagName !== 'SCRIPT'
            && !elements[i].children.length
            && elements[i].textContent.indexOf(query) > -1) {
            out.push(elements[i]);
        }
    }
    return out;
}

// call finder with the parameter you want
var arr = finder('Hello');

// call the update function with the array
// passed back from finder
updateDom(arr);

function updateDom(arr) {

    // loop over the elements array from finder
    // and change the contents
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        arr[i].textContent = 'Hello Mikołaj Król';
    }
}
```

Note that `textContent` is IE9+.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6vaokv68/18/)